# Tracking transfer progress -> which resource?

Tags: c#, azure

I'm creating an application handling local file transfers to an Azure account.
In cases of directories, I build a list of files to transfer asynchronously.

I'm using a progress handler to track number of bytes transfered for each file in real time. It uses an Action object. Like this:

```
Action<TransferStatus> action = (status) => {  
    Console.WriteLine("Transfered bytes: {0}", status.BytesTransferred); 
};
```

Where Action is defined in System as

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj)
```

And TransferStatus is a seal class containing no method and only four attributes (BytesTransferred, NumberOfFilesTransferred, NumberofFilesSkipped, NumberOfFilesFailed) but nothing relating to the input resource.

Finally, each time I have to track transfer progress:

```
Progress<TransferStatus> progress = new Progress<TransferStatus>(action);
SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext(null);
context.ProgressHandler = progress;
```

However, I would like to know in the action body which resource (i.e. source file) is concerned, like this:

```
Action<TransferStatus> action = (status) => {  
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", getFile()); // ???
    Console.WriteLine("Transfered bytes: {0}", status.BytesTransferred); 
};
```

Action is not a class but a delegate, so it cannot be extended (no possibility to add a property to assign the input resource when the action is instandiated for each file).
No possibility to use a Dictionnary to link the status to the file since the status is not instanciated by myself. Idem for Action (no possibility to use keyword "this" inside the delegate body).

Maybe there is a simple way to get file name from the action ?
Anyone knowing the Azure API ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think some context is missing here. How is `TransferStatus` implemented? Why can't you simply extend it to include the data you want?

Comment: TransferStatus class is not instanciated by myself but inside the framework. So I can't determine where it's instanciated (cannot determine the context). Moreover, it's a sealed class, so it cannot be extended.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. It was a false problem.